# Python conditional format

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, format, conditional-statements

I want to avoid the code that follows. I need to format one integer in a way that it takes his deserved place. Probably I could explain it better. I do not know. But it needs a very short look at that piece of code to understand what do I want to do. It is very simple.

```py
if   a > 9999999: print('{:08d}'.format(a))
elif a > 999999: print('{:07d}'.format(a))
elif a > 99999: print('{:06d}'.format(a))
elif a > 9999: print('{:05d}'.format(a))
elif a > 999: print('{:04d}'.format(a))
elif a > 99: print('{:03d}'.format(a))
elif a > 9: print('{:02d}'.format(a))
else:      print('{:01d}'.format(a))
```

This works, but I guess there is a better way to do the same. Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You want to print a number with as much space as… it takes… to print it…?! That's what happens when you simply `print` the number:

```
>>> a = 123456789
>>> print(a)
123456789
>>> a = 1
>>> print(a)
1
```